# VisualSvn Server svnsync sync-lock error

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnsync

I've a primary svn server on linux and i'm making a read-only synced version using VisualSvn Server.
I'm following the tutorials on

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication

and

http://blogs.geniuscode.net/RyanDHatch/?p=9

but I'm still getting the error

```
svnsync: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svnsync: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svnsync: Error setting property 'sync-lock':
could not remove a property
```

I've used both the svn admin console to add in appropriate hook on the target server (I'm guessing its the target server that requires this hook, not the source server), both one with some batch logic to check user names, and one that is just "@ECHO OFF" and nothing changes, I still get the error. I've checked the repo hooks folder and VisualSvn server creates .cmd files, so I tried copying the files without extensions which is the *nix convention, still no change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You `pre revision property change hook` on target server should return zero. For example:

> exit 0

Answer (score 0):

When creating the repo in VisualSVN Server, I've frequently checked the "yes, please create tags, branches, and trunk" checkbox, which totally fries svnsync.  Ensure you don't check that box.  Try creating a new repository in VisualSVN Server, setting the hook (yes, in the target server), and then pushing go.  I also typically remove the `--non-interactive` as I like to watch what is happening.  http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2006/09/14/using-svnsync/ is the tutorial I usually use, though it doesn't seem any better / worse than your links.

Comment: You shouldn't choose to create default structure for a target svnsync repository.

svnsync initialization requires target repository to be completely fresh and virgin, per SVNBook: "...by default, it must not yet have any version history in it". See SVNBook reference at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication